# Determining an $\mathbb{R}$-basis for $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2-x,y^2-y)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Question:

> Determine an $\mathbb{R}$-basis for $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2-x,y^2-y)$.

There is a similar question here [Linear basis for a quotient ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569901/linear-basis-for-a-quotient-ring),
which involves determining a basis for $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+k)$. But I am confused how to apply this method since the ideal we are quotienting by is generated by two polynomials.

Should we do something like: take an $f\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ and consider $(f \pmod{x^2-x})\pmod{y^2-y}$? But this seems very messy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the monomial standard basis of $R={\Bbb R}[x,y]/\langle x^2-x,y^2-y\rangle$ is given by $\{1,x,y,xy\}$, since $x^2-x=0$ and $y^2-y=0$ in $R$.

Note for T. Stark: Consider all monomials $x^iy^j$ in the polynomial ring ${\Bbb R}[x,y]$ and apply the reduction $x^2=x$ and $y^2=y$ in $R$.

Comment: Sorry why does it follow from $x^2-x=0$ and $y^2-y=0$ in $R$ that ${1,x,y,xy}$ is a basis?

Comment: I believe it is easy to see that $1,x,y,xy$ generate the quotient. (Any polynomial with monomials such as $x^ay^b$ where either $a\ge 2$ or $b\ge 2$ is equivalent to one of a lower degree because $x^2=x$ and $y^2=y$.) @Wuestenfux: How do we prove that they are linearly independent?

Comment: @StinkingBishop: If $a + bx + cy +dxy=0$ in the quotient ring, then by the natural surjection $a+bx+cy+dxy=0$ in the polynomial ring. But in the polynomial ring $a=b=c=d=0$. Done.

Answer (score 0):

There is a surjective map from $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ to the quotient, so an $\mathbb{R}$ basis of the polynomial ring will map to a generating set (not necessarily a basis) of the quotient. So take your favorite basis of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, and then figure out which of those elements become redundant after the map.

Comment: I am confused in actually figuring out which elements are redundant due to quoitenting by two polynomials. 

Also as an $\mathbb{R}$ vector space $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ is infinite dimensional so I'm not sure how picking a basis will help